# Using seaborn (or matplotlib) to create a scatterplot with the points made up of rectangles

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

As the title states I want to create a scatterplot, but I want the plot to be made up of rectangles. The obvious answer so far is to set the marker to 's' as so:

```
+---+---+-------+
| X | Y | Data  |
+---+---+-------+
| 1 | 1 |     0 |
| 1 | 2 |     1 |
+---+---+-------+

import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, hue='Data', x='X', y='Y',
                legend='full', marker='s')
```

What if I want to increase or decrease the distance (on the graph) between each point for x and y? Like for this graph above they'll just be two equal squares right next to each other, but what if I want them to be really long or wide rectangles (but still only be at points (1,1) and (1,2))?

The ultimate goal is to create a graph with a long (or wide, never both) rectangles representing points just like in the df above. This is just the way I thought of it. If there are better ways please recommend them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bar plot using the x-values as x, the y-values as bottom, and set your chosen rectangle width and height for the bars:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randint(1, 10, 20),
                   'y': np.random.randint(1, 10, 20),
                   'data': np.random.randint(0, 4, 20)})
cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma')
norm = plt.Normalize(df['data'].min(), df['data'].max())
c = [cmap(norm(d)) for d in df['data'].values]
rwidth = 0.8  # desired width of the little rectangles
rheight = 0.6  # desired height of the little rectangles

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x=df['x'], height=rheight, bottom=df['y'] - rheight / 2, width=rwidth, color=c)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.use_sticky_edges = False
ax.legend(handles=[plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, label=d, color=cmap(norm(d)))
                   for d in range(df['data'].min(), df['data'].max() + 1)])
plt.show()
```

[image: scatterplot with rectangles]

Comment: Idk why I didn't think of using a bar plot. I was so focused on using the scatterplot for some reason lol. I'll try this out, thanks!